# Timeout error on Heroku when rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rake, assets

My application files are as... 
application.js

```
    //= require jquery
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require ckeditor-jquery
    //= require ckeditor/config
    // require bootstrap.min
    //= require bootstrap-datepicker.min
    //= require chosen.jquery.min
    //= require common
    //= require ace-elements.min
    //= require registration
    //= require courses
    //= require instructors
    //= require jsapi
    //= require donation
```

application.css

```
    *= require bootstrap.min
    *= require font-awesome
    *= require jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min
    *= require datepicker
    *= require ace-fonts
    *= require ace.min
    *= require ace-rtl.min
    *= require ace-skins.min
    *= require chosen.min
    *= require custom
    *= require instructors
    *= require_self
```

As I think it may cause of ckeditor jquery loading too much time or may be m wrong. 
At locally, *rake assets:percompile* is fine but taking too much time more than 10 min.

Comment: I have solve this issue. If our  precompile take time at heroku then we should do 

        rake assets:precompile           (at local)
        commit public/assets             (no need to push at git)
        git push heroku master
Through this U can skip the precompilation at heroku side.